# proof of Existence of Accumulation Point in $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\ E = \Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$

In this set, I would like to show that $(0,0)$ is an accumulation point of $E$.

Below is my proof:

> For every open set $U$ which contains $(0,0)$,  there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U $.
>
> Since every $B((0,0), \epsilon) $ contains point of $E$ other than $(0,0)$, it's an accumulation point.

How is this proof? Is it sufficiently rigorous? I doubt that there's more explanation about why that epsilon ball contains point of $E$ other than $(0,0)$.

Comment: Read [MSE cheatsheet on ChatJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your MathJax formatting in future questions.

Comment: What does Bbb mean used to denote real number?

Comment: For the real set and the backslash for set difference, use `\mathbb{R}` and `\backslash`. Also, you can use greek letters by writing `\epsilon` or `\Omega`, for example.

Comment: @jackerysmith Bbb means blackboard bold, which is the typeface used for  the real numbers, that is `\Bbb{R}` for $\Bbb{R}$.  It's also used for things like the rational numbers, that is `\Bbb{Q}` for $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AccumulationPoint.html

According to that definition you'll need to actively construct a sequence tending toward $(0,0).$ Otherwise what you've shown is correct, in spirit, but you'll either need to use what you've written to show there is a sequence, or you can just explicitly construct one. I suggest the latter.

Comment: @justin It feels slightly ambiguous to me to understand about constructing sequence tending toward (0,0) could you give me a example so that I could understand how to represent one without loss of generality?

Comment: You probably mean to have $x=0$. So just choose $N\in\mathbb N$ with $B(0,\frac 1N)\subset U$. Then the sequence $\{(\frac1n,0):n\in\mathbb N, n>N\}$ does the trick.

Comment: I edited the question in case of x = 0. thx,.

Comment: @MPW This question would reveal that I didn't fully get the notion of accumulation point. "why" do we need to construct the sequence that trending into 0? since natural numbers are part of Real numbers?

Comment: Try constructing one that tends to zero in $\Bbb{R}$ then try to do the same thing in 2D. If you need more help you'll get it.

Comment: @justin How's it related to construct that tend(or sequence) with checking out whether the every Ball contains other point of E? Is it related to the characterization of Real Number?

Comment: Write down any sequence that tends to zero in $\Bbb{R}$ then try to convince yourself that every open ball (deleted or not) about $0$ will intersect your set of sequence terms at infinitely many points

Comment: @justin following your direction I had constructed sequence $ {1/n : n > N \ in\ \Bbb N }$. Then open ball of 0 will intersect given sequence at each case of radius that coincide with the same radius of $ n > N$.

Comment: So now try to do that with two coordinates.

Comment: @justin in $ \Bbb R^2$  if choose a sequence $ {(0, 1/n) : n > N \ in\ \Bbb N }$, Then open ball of $(0,0)$ will intersect given sequence at each case of radius that coincide with the same radius of $ n > N $

Comment: Right idea. So you've found a sequence tending to (0,0) and now you just need to weave this into a proof

Comment: get it. this construction Renders that Every epsilon ball of 0 would contains point in E since each terms of constructed sequence is in E.

Comment: @justin But one more qustion, how could my sequence guarantee that I had checked "every" open ball of $(0,0)$? since I had checked only in case of my sequence which represents the case of 1/n, which is all rational not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your proof is correct.

The second line is mere assertion. You need to show that $B((0,0),\epsilon)$ contains a point other than $(0,0)$.

In this case, you can show that a specific point, say $(\epsilon/2,0)$,  is in $B((0,0),\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

For every open set $U$ which contains $(0,0)$,  there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U $.

If we choose a sequence $ {1/n : n > N \ in\ \Bbb N }$, of

which terms are all in E. Then $B((0,0), \epsilon) $ will intersect given

sequence at each case of radius that coincide with the same radius of $ n > N$.

As shown above, since every $B((0,0), \epsilon) $ contains point of $E$ other

than $(0,0)$, $\ (0,0)$ is an accumulation point.